# Can an IPS panel in a monitor help relieve eye strain?

Tags: computers, eye-strain, led-lights, artificial-tear-eye-drops, technology

Working as a programmer, I have problems with my eyes. I am using eyedrops, but that does not help. Up till now I always worked with LED monitors a colleague told me that I could try one with an [IPS panel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPS_panel). Is it possible that a monitor with an IPS panel would help and why?

Comment: I have no idea about IPS, but have you considered using a projector projecting at a fairly small area (e.g. the equivalent of a 30'' display, let's say)?

Comment: You didn't mention brightness. What brightness are you calibrating to? Also if you don't have it already, install bias lighting on the back of your panel, preferably white.

Answer (score 0):

As a programmer who has been through much more severe eye strain than you for a decade, I know of how people recommend eye drops, special lenses and screens as a cure. DOES NOT WORK.
What helped in my recovery are three simple things:

1. Eight hours of **uninterrupted** sleep every night. Even 7 hours is not enough. It has to be eight. Children need [more than 8 hours of sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep#Recommendations).
2. Closing my eyes and relaxing my neck muscles and face muscles after 20 minutes of computer use and then waiting until the strain subsides (the wait is usually 5 minutes, but it could be lesser for you).
3. Getting a well balanced diet of properly cooked food. When food is not fully cooked or burnt, it causes stomach discomfort that leads to sleep loss. Also, your eye muscles need protein and the rest of your body needs a lot of essential nutrition to keep all functions running well. So search for what a "well balanced" diet is, and eat it.

This problem of severe eye strain and people not knowing what to do, is quite evident from blogs like [this](https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2017/2/21/10-years-of-eye-pain) and the comments on the blog where more people are reporting how severe it got for them. Don't let it get severe. Start getting rest and sleep.